# OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect in PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using Auto Py to Exe to convert a .py file into a .exe file. All my code is in a single file but I do have a seperate icon (X2P.ico) and 3 .txt files as well. I am currently using Windows 10. This was the command generated by Auto Py to Exe

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "C:/Project/X2P.ico" --add-data "C:/Project/AppFinal_Template1.txt;." --add-data "C:/Project/AppFinal_Template2.txt;." --add-data "C:/Project/AppFinal_TemplateNames.txt;."  "C:/Project/X2P_main.py"
```

But on running the above command I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 268, in UpdateResource
    _resource._UpdateResource(
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_resource.py", line 130, in _UpdateResource
    check_false(
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

which is followed by

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 684, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpoo3n_0ls\X2P_main.spec", line 21, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 450, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 549, in assemble
    icon.CopyIcons(tmpnm, self.icon)
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 216, in CopyIcons
    return CopyIcons_FromIco(dstpath, [srcpath])
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 159, in CopyIcons_FromIco
    win32api.UpdateResource(hdst, RT_ICON, iconid, data)
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 268, in UpdateResource
    _resource._UpdateResource(
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (87, 'UpdateResource', 'The parameter is incorrect')

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

Please help me resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command from the folder where your X2P_main.py is located. With this below command

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "C:/Project/X2P.ico" --add-data "C:/Project/AppFinal_Template1.txt;." --add-data "C:/Project/AppFinal_Template2.txt;." --add-data "C:/Project/AppFinal_TemplateNames.txt;." X2P_main.py
```